How to have noise cancellation for microfone in Linux?
os - pop!_os
I have been using this OS as a dual boot. The mic sensitivity is very high compared to windows. The mic picks up road car sounds like crystal clear compared to Windows. I tried NoiseTorch but its not at all working at all and I saw "PipeWire support is in alpha quality" so its not fully supported in pipewire. I did pactl info it returned:
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 776
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: rohit
Host Name: pop-os
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.3)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.6.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_06_00.6.analog-stereo
Cookie: 7af9:f9aa

I tried to install pulseaudio as NoiseTorch is supported in it but pipewire is not letting me.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-pipewire : Depends: pipewire-alsa but it is not going to be installed
                Conflicts: pulseaudio
                Conflicts: pulseaudio:i386
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

I manually kept the mic sensitivity low but it automatically increases and picks up every noise of my surrounding.
sorry for bad english. Comment for any clarify.
